# React Table 7 - How to change the state of an individual button created dynamically by the React-Table API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I am using React Table 7 to create a table with the first cell of each row being a ChecOut/CheckIn Button. My goal is to create a tool where people can CheckOut and CheckIn equipment. [My React Table CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-checkin-checkout-qor10?file=/src/App.js)

The idea is that when a user clicks the button, it will change from `"CheckOut"` to `"CheckIn"` and vise versa. It will also change the `color` of the row when Checked out. I was able to accomplish this with JQuery (code is in the sandbox under the App() functional component) but want to avoid that and am sure it's easily doable in react.

My issue is changing the state of an individual button and which functional component to define it in. The `<Button>` elements are created dynamically by the React-Table, defined in the columns object under the App functional component.

```js
      {
        Header: "CheckIn/Out",
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <Button
            key={row.id}
            id={row.id}
            onClick={e => checkClick(e)}
            value={checkButton.value}
          >
            {checkButton.value}
          </Button>
        )
      }
```

I tried passing a function to `onChnage` attribute on the `<Button>` element. In that function I updated the state of the `<Button>` to change the string value from `"CheckOut"` to `"CheckIn"` but that does not work. At first, that changed the name (state) of All the `<Button>` elements.  Not sure if the state will live in the App() component or the TableRe() functional component. Or do I need to use state at all?

I basically built this on top of the editable table code available on the React-Table website [React-Table Editable Data CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/editable-data) , examples section [React-Table Examples](https://react-table.js.org/examples/simple#editable-data) .

Any help is much appreciated!

---

### data.js

```
import React from "react";

// export default random => {
//   let arr = [];
//   for (let i = 0; i < random; i++) {
//     arr.push({
//       first: chance.name(),
//       last: chance.last(),
//       birthday: chance.birthday({ string: true }),
//       zip: chance.zip()
//     });
//   }
//   return arr;
// };

const temp_data = [
  {
    firstName: "johny",
    lastName: "Bravo",
    age: "23",
    visits: "45",
    progress: "complete",
    status: "all done"
  },
  {
    firstName: "johny",
    lastName: "Bravo",
    age: "23",
    visits: "45",
    progress: "complete",
    status: "all done"
  }
];

const ArrayData = () => {
  const data = temp_data.map(item => {
    return {
      firstName: item.firstName,
      lastName: item.lastName,
      age: item.age,
      visits: item.visits,
      progress: item.progress,
      status: item.status
    };
  });
  return data;
};

// Do not think there is any need to memoize this data since the headers
// function TempData() {
//   const data = React.useMemo(ArrayData, []);
//   return data;
// }

export default ArrayData;
```

Comment: Please add the data that you creates rows for in your question

Comment: @Hagai thanks for reaching out. I have added the data.js file that provides the data for the rows in the post just now. Are you unable to view the file on the codesanbox that I linked in the original post?